# Simulink: FOR iterator and selector block

Tags: matlab, for-loop, signal-processing, matlab-figure, simulink

I am trying to have simple functionality using a 2D vector [M x N]. My intention is to iterate the rows and read the columns. So, I use a FOR iterator subsystem, set the FOR iterator from 0 -> M-1 and then perform some operations on the read data.

For the sake of simplicity in the example below, I have used the only a vector of size 1X10 : [100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000]

[image: example]

However, the for iterator does not show any change of value ( both iterator and the read column ). I put scope and I see only last value i.e. 900 of the vector.

[image: inside the for iterator subsystem]

Scope on the output of subsystem>

[image: Scope on the output of for subsytem]

Scope on the for iterator block>

[image: Scope on for iterator block]

Block parameters of FOR iterator:

[image: FOR ITERATOR parameters]

Parameters of SELECTOR block:

[image: SELECTOR block parameters]
The sample time is set to -1.

**Expected output:**
My expectation is that I read a column for each indexes and thus the scope on subsystem output should linear change, 100 -> 200 -> 300 -> 400 .......-> 1000. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is [intended behavior](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100384-how-can-i-use-for-iterator-block-to-produce-and-display-the-sequence-from-0-to-49-on-a-scope), you always see the state at the end of the block execution. Your primary option is to [create a vector](https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/iterated-assignment-with-assignment-block.html) using an assignment block. This way the vector holds one value for each iteration.